# RecyclerView is not populating items whereas Adapter and ArrayList already has data

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

`recycerViewOrderNewItem` and `offlineOrderProductListProductList` are two `recyclerviews` and those were initialized in `onCreate()` method.

```
        recycerViewOrderNewItem = findViewById(R.id.recycerViewOrderNewItem);
        recycerViewOrderNewItem.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

        offlineOrderProductListProductList = findViewById(R.id.offlineOrderProductListProductList);
        offlineOrderProductListProductList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
```

The below is where I am retrieving my data as `List<>`

```
    List<NewOrderEntryModel> allItemsOfOrder = new InitializeDatabase(OrderEntryActivity.this).myAppDatabaseInit.myDao().getAllNewOrderEntryModelByRefID(SalesID);
```

and I am setting adapter like this for both of them...

```
    offlineOrderProductListProductList.setAdapter(new NewOrderEntryAdapter(OrderEntryActivity.this, (ArrayList<NewOrderEntryModel>) allItemsOfOrder));

    recycerViewOrderNewItem.setAdapter(new NewOrderEntryAdapter(OrderEntryActivity.this, (ArrayList<NewOrderEntryModel>) allItemsOfOrder));
```

for `offlineOrderProductListProductList` recyclerview is working but for `recycerViewOrderNewItem` `recyclerview` is not working

I have debugged the code. `ArrayList` contains data.

> Below is my adapter code...

```
    public class NewOrderEntryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewOrderEntryAdapter.NewOrderEntryAdapterViewHolder>{

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<NewOrderEntryModel> newOrderEntryModels;

    public NewOrderEntryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NewOrderEntryModel> newOrderEntryModels) {
        this.context = context;
        this.newOrderEntryModels = newOrderEntryModels;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NewOrderEntryAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_order_entry_detail,parent,false);

        return new NewOrderEntryAdapterViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NewOrderEntryAdapterViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        NewOrderEntryModel orderEntryModel = newOrderEntryModels.get(position);

        //Data

        final String name = orderEntryModel.getProductName();
        final String totalPrice = String.valueOf(orderEntryModel.getPBSalesTotal());
        final String code = String.valueOf(orderEntryModel.getPCode());
        final String quantity = String.valueOf(orderEntryModel.getPBInQty());
        final String price = String.valueOf(orderEntryModel.getPBSalesPrice());
        final String productID = String.valueOf(orderEntryModel.getPBProductID());


        // Binding
        holder.tvProductNameOrderEntry.setText(name);
        holder.tvProductTotalPriceOrderEntry.setText(totalPrice);
        holder.tvProductCodeOrderEntry.setText(code);
        holder.tvProductQuantityOrderEntry.setText(quantity);
        holder.tvProductPriceOrderEntry.setText(price);


        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //Toast.makeText(context, "Reference id: "+orderEntryModel.getPBRefID()+" Table ID: "+orderEntryModel.getID(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if(orderEntryModel.getPBRefID()==null){
                    //Toast.makeText(context, "Reference id: "+orderEntryModel.getPBRefID()+" Table ID: "+orderEntryModel.getID(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    openDetailActivity(String.valueOf(position),"","",name,totalPrice,code,quantity,price,productID);
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Reference id: "+orderEntryModel.getPBRefID()+" Table ID: "+orderEntryModel.getID(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    openDetailActivity(String.valueOf(position),Integer.toString(orderEntryModel.getID()),orderEntryModel.getPBRefID(),name,totalPrice,code,quantity,price,productID);
                }

                //Toast.makeText(context, context.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return newOrderEntryModels.size();
    }

    public class NewOrderEntryAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView tvProductNameOrderEntry
                ,tvProductTotalPriceOrderEntry
                ,tvProductCodeOrderEntry
                ,tvProductQuantityOrderEntry
                ,tvProductPriceOrderEntry;

        public NewOrderEntryAdapterViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvProductNameOrderEntry = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductNameOrderEntry);
            tvProductTotalPriceOrderEntry = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductTotalPriceOrderEntry);
            tvProductCodeOrderEntry = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductCodeOrderEntry);
            tvProductQuantityOrderEntry = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductQuantityOrderEntry);
            tvProductPriceOrderEntry = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvProductPriceOrderEntry);
        }
    }

    public void openDetailActivity(String position,
                                   String id,
                                   String pbRef,
                                   String productName,
                                   String totalPrice,
                                   String productCode,
                                   String quantity,
                                   String productPrice,
                                   String productID){

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewItemDetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("position",position);
        intent.putExtra("id",id);
        intent.putExtra("pbRef",pbRef);
        intent.putExtra("productName",productName);
        intent.putExtra("totalPrice",totalPrice);
        intent.putExtra("productCode",productCode);
        intent.putExtra("quantity",quantity);
        intent.putExtra("productPrice",productPrice);
        intent.putExtra("productID",productID);

        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

please help me out with this problem...

Comment: Please provide the adapter code.

Comment: 1. Have you checked the xml for the recyclerview to make sure you are not using match-parent for the height of the recyclerview item? 2. Debug the code from your recyclerview adapter class to make sure the recyclerview is actually seeing the array

Comment: check if recycleViews work separately by commenting each. If that works most probably the issue must be with the XML `height=match_parent` .

Comment: I always use wrap_content for recyclerView.

Comment: Both recyclerView's are the same page?

Comment: yes both are at the same page...

Comment: how to make sure that the recyclerview is actually seeing the array @TharushaShehan

Comment: Does the list in adapter gets populated with the data in the array list passed as a parameter to Adapter class ?

Comment: Please provide XML for both recycler view layout and its items

Comment: @WasiSadman try debugging after commenting each line of `rcycleView.setadapter` and see whether each view is populating itself. 
If you want to know the specific instance of seeing the array you will have to get an idea on "recycle view life cycle" in android.

Comment: Done... I have just created them in a new separate method and initialized them separately... that did for me... Thank you all and thanks to @TharushaShehan

Comment: You welcome @WasiSadman happy to be of help in somehow.

Comment: something interesting happened with that ... recyclerview has data... but it shows data when the softkeyboard is on the screen for the first editText layout... some how it is refreshing or initializing the recyclerview which i don't know why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should initialize your adapter and recyclerview clearly.

> allItemsOfOrder can be global like this

```
List<NewOrderEntryModel> allItemsOfOrder = new ArrayList<>();
```

Take the code below as an example:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycerViewOrderNewItem);

    mAdapter = new NewOrderEntryAdapter(this,allItemsOfOrder);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Then you should add orders to your list

> allItemsOfOrder can be global like this

```
allItemsOfOrder.add(/*Something*/);
```

Then you should notify your adapter like below...

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

you can use this [link](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/) as a reference.